# The meaning of "Get under her skirt" from a book "captivated by you"

Tags: sentence-meaning

[image]

What is meant by "Get under her skirt"

What is meant by "I so don't"

..

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  They can't be searched or indexed, and they're not friendly to users with vision problems or on slow internet connections.  Also, what does the picture add to the question that couldn't have been put in text?

Answer (score 4):

With **I *so* don't...** the word **so** is an intensifier, whose meaning is **to a very great extent**.  The meaning of the phrase is "I am not *at all* someone who likes to mess with people's lives".

To **get under a woman's skirt** is to advance beyond flirting or dalliance to intimate sexual encounter.

Comment: Why did the author add don't?????? shouldn't it be "I so not" or I am not so"

Comment: *I so do not [like to mess with people's lives]*.  The words are a rejoinder to the preceding accusation spoken by her friend.